# Using XSLT How to transform character to Unicode value

Tags: xslt

Using XSLT to transform from xml to another xml how to convert
char value to its unicode value

Example:-
Converting **U** In first XML

to be **85** in the transformed XML

the problem is, how to convert character to Unicode value ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy with XSLT 2.0 or later and the function `string-to-codepoints` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-to-codepoints e.g. `string-to-codepoints('U')`.

See online sample at http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCP.

Comment: I have this error when trying to transform
'string-to-codepoints()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Comment: Well, I clearly stated that it can be done with XSLT 2.0 or later so of course you need to use an XSLT 2.0 or later processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Altova Raptor or similar or an IDE like oXygen, Stylus Studio, XmlSpy that supports XSLT 2.0.